# What's wrong with my proof ??

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, open-map

This question was on my exam but apparently my answer was wrong as I only got half of the point:
Suppose $p:X \to Y$ is an open map, prove if $A$ is open in $X$ then $q:A \to p(A)$ obtained by restricting $p$ is also an open map.

My proof: Let $U$ be open in $A$. We have that $q(U) = p(U)$ is open in $Y$, hence it's open in $p(A)$. So q is an open map.

This sounded like a quick excercise but apparently my proof needs improvement. What's wrong about my proof?

Comment: Why is $U$ open in $X$?

Comment: $q$ does not map $A$ into $X$.

Comment: The codomain of $q$ is important (and, as Kavi pointed out, it being $X$ makes no sense). If it's supposed to be $Y$, then it makes no sense to conclude with "Hence $q(U)$ is open in $p(A)$", because your goal should be to prove that $q(U)$ open in $Y$, period. If it's supposed to be $q:A\to p(A)$, then it's probably what Servaes and others have said.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy my bad, sorry. I misread as I was typing the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that $p(U)$ is open. Why is that? The set $U$ is an open subset of $A$, but you should deduce from this that therefore $U$ is an open subset of $X$ (and this is where the fact that $A$ is open is used; it is *not* true in general). Then, yes, you can deduce that $p(U)$ is indeed an open subset of $Y$.

Comment: Carlos If you feel.that my answer is basicly yours, I delete. Thanks.

Comment: Because we can say that U is the intersection of O and A where O is open in X

Comment: @HodaBibo Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @PeterSzilas No need for that, but thank you for asking.

Comment: Jose Carlos Santos. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To be certain why you didn't get full credit, you should ask whomever graded the exercise. The most likely reason seems that you conclude that $p(U)$ is open in $p(A)$, without arguing why $U$ is open in $X$. Also, the codomain of $q$ is $Y$, not $p(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be open in $X$;

Then any open set $O$ in $A$ can be written as

$O=U \cap A$, where $U$ is open in $X;$

$O$ as the intersection of $U$ and $A$, which are both open in $X$, gives and open set $O$ in $X$.

Hence $f(O)$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open subset in $A$. Then for some open in $X$ like $O$, we have $U=O \cap A$.
Since $A$ is open in $X$ then $O  \cap A$ is also open in $X$. Hence, $q(U)=p(U)=p(O \cap A)$ is open in $Y$.
We conclude that $q(U)=p(U)$ is open in $p(A)$ since open sets in $p(A)$ are open sets in $Y$ contained in $p(A)$.